# autolayout with dynamics subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, ios-autolayout

[image]

I am trying to make home screen on my ios 10 app like on photo from above. Green view is actually scroll view and i set constraints for it to cover whole View. Everything on scrollView i want to make scrollable. Yellow part is collection view with prototype cell. Number of items on this view is 6. Cell consists of photo and title. Table view is list of news (photo + title). When start app in table view I load 10 last news and rest of the news I getting with "load more" mechanism. I need proper work of app even on landscape orientation. I have problem to define this layout because collection view and tableView have dynamic height and space between them must be fixed. Usually on almost all tutorials people just fixed scrollView and GridView and in that case app looks good on portrait orientation but i need a more flexibility. Is it possible to achieve this through auto layout and constraints and if yes what are correct directions

UPDATE:

[image]

Content view
[image]

Collection view

[image]

What I want to achieve is to make collection view as a two columns and 3 rows in portrait orientation and 3 columns and 2 rows on landscape. Currently I have collectionView with a scroll but I want to be expanded al the time because content of collectionView should consists of 6 highlighted news.

On viewDidLoad I tried to set table view on correct position (after collection view):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    collection.dataSource = self
    collection.delegate = self

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


   self.view.addConstraint(
        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: tableView,
            attribute: .top,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: collection,
            attribute: .bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 20
    ))



    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: collection.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height,width: tableView.frame.width,height: tableView.frame.width ); // set new position exactly

    downloadArticles(offset: "0") {}
}
```

An example of what I want to achieve is:

[image]

Currently I have this:

[image]

Comment: Autolayout can work with dynamic subviews. What is not working with your current set of constraints and what do you expect to happen?  Your question will need to be very clear in order for anyone to even have a chance at helping you.

Comment: In case you haven't already, all contents you want to display in your scrollview must be subviews inside a container view and this container view should be the only subview of the scrollview.

Comment: @Zhang: I already set it like you said

Comment: @Robotic Cat: I updated my question even with an example of what I want to achieve. I think that huge problem for me is collectionView. I still did not manage to show it in full size, without scrolling and with fixed space between it and tableView

Comment: Hang on, let me get this right, you want to see a grid of 6 news cell first, then when user scrolls down, they see a list of news (your tableview) or do you mean you see a grid of 6 cells, when use press a toggle button, the grid of 6 cells becomes a list of cells instead ?

Comment: yes you catch the point, I have grid with 6 cells and below grid is table view with a list o cells. tableView have its own scrolling system and that is fine.

Comment: I need a contentView with dynamic size not fixed as I found on many examples. Size of content view should be defined with size of collection view and table view but still did not manage this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "listCell")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // shrink wrap the collectionView and tableView to fit their content height snuggly
        self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView Methods -
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    func calculateGridCellSize() -> CGSize {
        // -----------------------------------------------------
        // Calculate the size of the grid cells
        // -----------------------------------------------------
        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height

        var width:CGFloat = 0
        var height:CGFloat = 0

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation)) {
            width = screenWidth / 2.0 - 0.5
            height = width
        }
        else {
            width = screenWidth / 3.0 - 1.0
            height = screenHeight / 2.0 - 0.5
        }

        let size:CGSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        return size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.calculateGridCellSize()
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            print("New screen size = \(size.width) x \(size.height)")
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (context) in
            self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Methods -
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "list cell \(indexPath.row)"
    }
}
```

For the interface layout, I did this:

1. Add `scrollView` to main view
2. Pin `scrollview` all four sides main view
3. Add `contentView` to `scrollView`
4. Pin `contentView` all four sides to `scrollView`
5. Make `contentView` width equal to `scrollView` width
6. Add `collectionView` to `contentView`
7. Add `tableView` to `contentView` and vertically below `collectionView`
8. Pin left, top, right of `collectionView` to `contentView`
9. Pin left, bottom, right of `tableView` to `contentView` and top of `tableView` to bottom of `collectionView`
10. Make `collectionView` height 667 and create IBOutlet `NSLayoutConstraint` for `collectionView` height (so we can update it later)
11. Make `tableView` height 667 and create IBOutlet `NSLayoutConstraint` for `tableView` height (also to update later)
12. Make `collectionView` min item spacing 1 and line spacing 1
13. Disable `scrollingEnabled` for `collectionView`
14. Disable `scrollingEnabled` for `tableView`
15. Connect `collectionView` datasource and delegate to controller
16. Connect `tableView` datasource and delegate to controller

Here's a screenshot of the layout if it's any help.

[image: layout screenshot]

Usually I build my UI using pure code and you would be able to copy and paste, hit the run button but since you're using using Storyboard, I showed it using Storyboard, hopefully you can follow my layout setup instructions.

Here's the result:

[image: portrait screenshot 1]
[image: portrait screenshot 2]
[image: portrait screenshot 3]
[image: landscape screenshot 1]
[image: landscape screenshot 2]
[image: landscape screenshot 3]

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I just had to change viewDidLoad func and initialize delegate and data source:        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self, after this lines everything works properly. Thank you so much